# How to determine the time complexity of this loop?

Tags: data-structures

```
x=1;
While(x<n)
{
x=x + n/100;
}
```

I'm trying to figure out if it's o(n) or o(1). Because no matter what we put in n's place I think the loop will go just 10 times.

Comment: why you think it will go only by 10 times

Comment: Have you tried `n=2`?

Answer (score 0):

lets say n=1.1
then it will go for 10 times and if n=1.2 loop will go on for 17 times
and if n=2 it will go on for 50 times and when n>=101 loop will be repeated 100 times even if n=10^10000 else you can figure out

Comment: can you explain properly

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you're wrong it it being `O(n)` or `O(1)` and this is immediately clear by the fact that it can't be `O(1)`, because it takes different numbers of iterations for varying values of `n`(even looking at n = 1,2,3,4,5), and it can't be `O(n)` because it doesn't grow linearly.

Even through a bit of manual calculation you can see clearly that it won't always run 10 times. Examine the following short python program:

```
def t(n):
    x = 1
    c = 0
    while x < n:
        c += 1
        x += n/100
    return c

a = []
for i in range(10000):
    a += [i/100 + 1]

with open("out.csv","w") as f:
    for i in a:
        f.write(str(i) + "," + str(t(i)) + "\n")
```

Using Excel or some other application you can easily trend the number of iterations taken to see the following curve:

[image]

It is immediately clear at this point that the number of iterations taken is logarithmic in the range `{0:100}` with any `n < 1` taking 0 iterations and `n > 100` taking 100 operations. So while Big-O notation wasn't my best subject, I would guess that the time complexity is thus `O(log(n))`.